# ¿Por qué el código siguiente no muestra el producto correcto de los números comprendidos entre dos valores en jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bucles, botón, while

¡Hola! Mi intención sería pedirle al usuario dos números y luego el programa me daría el producto de los números comprendidos entre esos dos valores.

¿Alguien sabe si faltaría actualizar algo?

```
let num1;
let num2;
let producto = 1;

$("#btnIngresar").click(mostrarProducto);
function mostrarProducto(){
    num1 = Number($("#txtNum1").val());
    num2 = Number($("#txtNum2").val());
    while(num1 <= num2){
        producto = producto * num1;
        $("#pResultado").html(`${producto}`);
        num1++;
    }
}
```

Les puedo dejar el código HTML de referencia también:

```
<body>
    <label for="txtNum1">Número 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNum1">
    <label for="txtNum2">Número 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNum2">
    <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngresar">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Porqué usas un bucle `while`? ¿Entiendes lo que hace tu código realmente?

Comment: Estoy intentando aprender e implementar estructuras repetitivas a algunos problemas, en este caso pensé que si lograba que el programa leyera la cantidad de números entre el num1 y el num2, podría yo después indicar que me diera el resultado del producto entre esos dos valores inclusive.

Comment: El propio ciclo while que pusiste te esta saboteando amigo...

Comment: La condición del while puede no cumplirse si por ejemplo el num1 es un 2 y el num2 es un 1, nunca entraría al while, explica un poco mejor que es lo que necesitas hacer. Saludos.

Comment: Hmm, así que, ¿no me conviene usar una estructura de repetición para que me de el producto de los números comprendidos entre esos dos?

Comment: Para nada amigo, no es buena idea usar ese while...

Comment: Ya veo, entonces, tienes alguna sugerencia de ¿cómo podría indicarle al programa que vaya "acumulando" los valores entre num1 y num2 (inclusive) para que me de el producto total? O sea, si se ingresa num1 = 2 y num2 = 5 entonces quiero determinar el resultado de: 2 * 3 * 4 * 5.

Comment: Para eso necesita un bucle `for`.

Comment: De hecho ni siquiera necesita un ciclo, solo necesitas el evento que ya tienes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según uno de tus comentarios, lo que deseas es el valor de la multiplicación de los números enteros que se encuentran en un rango entre 2 valores que introduce el usuario.

Así, si el usuario introduce 2 y 5  necesitas calcular `2 * 3 * 4 * 5`.

Para esto es necesario un bucle `for`:

```js
$("#btnCalcular").click(mostrarProducto);

function mostrarProducto(){
    let num1 = Number($("#txtNum1").val());
    let num2 = Number($("#txtNum2").val());
    if(num1 >= num2) {
      $("#pResultado").html('Rango inválido');
      return;
    }
    let producto = 1;
    for(let i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
      producto *= i;
    }
    $("#pResultado").html(`${producto}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <label for="txtNum1">Número 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNum1">
    <br>
    <label for="txtNum2">Número 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNum2">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Calcular" id="btnCalcular">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
</body>
```

Como puedes apreciar, si no se cumple la condición de que `num1` sea menor estricto que `num2` se devuelve un mensaje de rango inválido.

Si el rango es válido se calcula el producto usando como valor el iterador `i`. El mismo en cada iteración tomará el valor adecuado y ser multiplicará por el valor del producto acumulado.

**EDICIÓN**

Puedes obtener el resultado usando `while`, caigo en la cuenta de que probablemente necesitas hacer con un bucle tipo `while`. Si bien no es tan intuitivo, el resultado lo puedes obtener igualmente con el bucle `while`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
$("#btnCalcular").click(mostrarProducto);

function mostrarProducto(){
    let num1 = Number($("#txtNum1").val());
    let num2 = Number($("#txtNum2").val());
    if(num1 >= num2) {
      $("#pResultado").html('Rango inválido');
      return;
    }
    let producto = 1;
    while(num1 <= num2) {
      producto *= num1;
      num1++;
    }
    $("#pResultado").html(`${producto}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <label for="txtNum1">Número 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNum1">
    <br>
    <label for="txtNum2">Número 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNum2">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Calcular" id="btnCalcular">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
</body>
```

Espero que esto te aclare la dificultad que tenías.

**P.D.:** para números muy grandes, el valor de este producto será `Infinity`, ya que no se puede representar correctamente.

Comment: ¡Muchísima gracias por tu detallada respuesta! Espero que puedas perdonar la demora.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let num1;
let num2;
let producto = 1;

$("#btnIngresar").click(mostrarProducto);
function mostrarProducto(){
    num1 = Number($("#txtNum1").val());
    num2 = Number($("#txtNum2").val());
    producto = num1 <= num2 ? producto * num1 * num2 : producto;
    $("#pResultado").html(`${producto}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <label for="txtNum1">Número 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNum1">
    <label for="txtNum2">Número 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNum2">
    <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngresar">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
</body>
```

No necesitas un ciclo, lo unico realizado en el código es quitar el ciclo y corregi esta parte de aquí, tu la tenias así:

```
producto = producto * num1;
```

A esto:

```
producto = producto * num1 * num2;
```

Puesto que al inicio producto vale 1.

Answer (score 0):

Creo entender lo que intentas hacer. Lo que buscas es mediante el ciclo while obtener la serie de productos existentes al multiplicar num1 por todos los valores existentes entre num1 y num2 pero tu código esta mal. Primero el valor inicial de la variable producto debe iniciarse en 0. Posteriormente dentro del ciclo la operación que debes realizar es: producto = producto + num1.
La condición del ciclo while es correcta.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta,  porfavor lee [answer]